# Multiple gretty configurations

Tags: gradle, jetty, gretty

We are experimenting with gradle. My project has following modules:

- client
- server
- tests

where server depends on client and tests depend on server.

Developing client/server requires running server with some certain configuration.

Tests have a custom java-exec task that configures and runs fitnesse, which has two modes - interactive, which allows you to run individual tests and silent, which runs the whole suite.

That gives 3 configurations of server i need to run:

- just server, development mode
- server and tests in interactive mode
- server and tests in silent mode

gretty documentation seems only to allow 1 task for integration tests to be included in gretty configuration. another problem is that this task has to be in the same module, but it's natural to put gretty in server/build.gradle and tests task into tests/build.gradle.

i also tried looking into webapp farms, but as i understand the idea there is to run several webapps simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

root.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:1.4.0"
    }
}
```

server.gradle:

```
if (condition) {
    apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'

    gretty {
    // some configuration here
    }
}
```

tests.gradle:

```
if (!condition) {
    apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'

    gretty {
    // different configuration here
    }
}
```